# What is the difference between $httpParamSerializerJQLike and encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain the difference between
`$httpParamSerializerJQLike`, available in Angular, and `encodeURIComponent`?

Do we need to execute `JSON.Stringify()` after serializing the params with `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`? My understanding is that `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` is Angular's version of `encodeURIComponent` and that it executes `JSON.Stringify` internally (of this part I'm not sure).

Answer (score 4):

`$httpParamSerializerJQLike` is not Angular's version of `encodeURIComponent`.

From the documentation for [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike):

> Alternative $http params serializer that follows jQuery's param() method logic.

`$httpParamSerializerJQLike` is used to create a serialized representation of an Array or plain object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. It is used to define query parameters for URIs. Its use is limited to arrays and plain objects.

For example:

```
$httpParamSerializerJQLike({a: 'two'}); // "a=two"
$httpParamSerializerJQLike('abc'); // "0=a&1=b&2=c"
```

You'll notice that the string `'abc'` is treated like an array of characters.

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character.

For example:

```
encodeURIComponent({a: 'two'}); // "%5Bobject%20Object%5D"
encodeURIComponent('abc'); // "abc"
encodeURIComponent('abc abc abc'); // "abc%20abc%20abc"
```

You can see that `encodeURIComponent` replaces special characters with the appropriate escape sequences and does not treat a string like a sequence of characters.

Comment: hi gnerkus, thanks for your response. After going through the logic for the $httpParamSerializerJQLike I understood that it do serialize as well as apply ecodeURIComponent, so this single function is doing two jobs. That is so cool.